# Generate multipage PDF UIView

Tags: swift, uitableview, pdf, uiview

I want to create multipage PDF of `self.view`. I have following `viewController` with `tableView` now I want to create the pdf of the view.

[image]

This is what I have done but it's create single page pdf only

```
func pdfDataWithTableView(tableView: UITableView) {
    let priorBounds = tableView.bounds
    let fittedSize = tableView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width:priorBounds.size.width, height:tableView.contentSize.height))
    tableView.bounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:fittedSize.width, height:fittedSize.height)
    let pdfPageBounds = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:tableView.frame.width, height:self.view.frame.height)
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds,nil)
    var pageOriginY: CGFloat = 0
    while pageOriginY < fittedSize.height {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.saveGState()
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: 0, y: -pageOriginY)
        tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.restoreGState()
        pageOriginY += pdfPageBounds.size.height
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    tableView.bounds = priorBounds
    var docURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last! as URL
    docURL = docURL.appendingPathComponent("myPassBook.pdf")
    pdfData.write(to: docURL as URL, atomically: true)
    share()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On save Button Call Below function

```
func createImg() -> UIImage {
        guard tblView.numberOfSections > 0, tblView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0) > 0 else {
            let errorImage = UIImage(named: "Error Image")
            return errorImage!
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: tblView.contentSize.width, height:  tblView.contentSize.height), false, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        let previousFrame = tblView.frame
        tblView.frame = CGRect(x: tblView.frame.origin.x, y:  tblView.frame.origin.y, width: tblView.contentSize.width, height: tblView.contentSize.height)
        // Draw view in that context
        tblView.layer.render(in: context!)
        tblView.frame = previousFrame
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        createPDFDataFromImage(image: image)
        return image;
    }
```

Create PDF from image and Share

```
func createPDFDataFromImage(image: UIImage){
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        let imgView = UIImageView.init(image: image)
        let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, imageRect, nil)
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        imgView.layer.render(in: context!)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

        //try saving in doc dir to confirm:
        let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last
        let path = dir?.appendingPathComponent("file.pdf")

        do {
            try pdfData.write(to: path!, options: NSData.WritingOptions.atomic)
        } catch {
            print("error catched")
        }
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [pdfData] , applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```